# A word/phrase to express deep sadness at a friend or loved one's stupidity?

Tags: nouns, phrase-requests, pejorative-language, emotions

I'm looking for a way to describe the feeling you get when someone you care about is being aggressively, intractably, and willfully ignorant or stupid about something.

It's something of a blend of disgust, disappointment, pity, and a sense that you wish you knew better people.

Something German+shmertz, perhaps? Mittleshmertz sounds appropriate, but given its existing meaning, I don't think it fits.

Ex. "His friend was filled with X as he realized his support for Trump was serious and not brilliant satire."

EDIT: The political example is just that, an example.  I'd also be willing to accept a word or phrase in another language that could be appropriated into English usage.

Comment: Disgust? Disappointment? Shock? I'm having a hard time, because I don't think I've ever experienced this emotion (in that my opinion of a person has never switched from "friendly respect or admiration" to "disgust at one's ignorance" in a short order, based on some instantaneous piece of new information. Surely one's sense of bafflement at another's beliefs develops over time?)

Comment: Maybe *ruefulness*?

Comment: I would have posted the German words but thi isn't the place

Comment: Dan, over time certainly, but time is infinitely divisible, and it's possible to take in a lot of impressions in a very short time period if you're scanning someone's facebook page, for instance. Shock and disappointment together come close.

Comment: Go to http://www.fluentu.com/german/blog/weird-german-words-vocabulary/ and look for lebensmude and fremdschamen.

Comment: vickyace, both apt words that come very close.  Lebensmude in particular, although it seems to have a connotation of physical harm rather than intellectual or social harm.  Is that right?

Comment: @JeffH. I think that an advantage of using a foreign word/phrase is that connotations can be subdued by context. It is alright to use it. Also, try http://www.popsci.com/science/article/2013-01/emotions-which-there-are-no-english-words-infographic

Answer (score 2):

"Self-loathing" for judging their friend? (Just kidding, the Trump thing has many of us baffled! lol!)  Though not really feeling the "sadness" part, but the closest I can come to the feeling you described is ***"bewilderment"***.

As defined by www.vocabulary.com:

> ***"Bewilderment*** is a state of being confused and puzzled. Bewilderment means not understanding, but it goes beyond that — it implies a state of complete mystification. People experience bewilderment when they are utterly baffled by the situation at hand."

Comment: Ha ha. Bewilderment comes close, but doesn't really capture the sense of loss that accompanies this emotion.

Comment: I know what you mean @JeffH.  Betrayal also comes to mind but that seems a little too personal and isn't quite right to me either.

Comment: How about combining bewilderment with dissonance? looking at the person with a dismaying sense of 'bewildered dissonance'?

Answer (score 2):

Consider **"commiseration"**, a feeling or expression of sorrow, pity or sympathy for somebody who made errors, had lost or had bad luck.

> Examples:
>
> - *Time would heal the wound that had been inflicted; and
>   incline them to look with commiseration on youthful errors easy to
>   repair*.
> - *All of the ‘losing’ competitors are invited to commiseration drinks at the hotel*.

Answer (score 1):

**Disillusionment**

> dis·il·lu·sion·ment noun a feeling of disappointment resulting from
>   the discovery that something is not as good as one believed it to be.
>   "the high abstention rate at the election reflected the voters'
>   growing disillusionment with politics"

google disillusionment

Comment: A good answer, and while it could be used this way, it doesn't quite capture the connotation without additional explanation. Leaning toward fremdschamen at the moment.